# Unable to fetch UnifiedPolicy.User.Read roles using MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The `Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ServicePrincipal` has two roles: `UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read` and  `UnifiedPolicy.User.Read`, but executing the below command the `UnifiedPolicy.User.Read` is not listed either in AppRoles or oAuth2Permissions, but i can see `UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read` under app roles.

```
$referenceServicePrincipal = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter ("appId eq '870c4f2e-85b6-4d43-bdda-6ed9a579b725'")
```

I am under the impressions that the `UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read` should be listed, where am i going wrong?  I am registering the app using PowerShell and the above command forms part of the script.

Updated 2022/10/30:  Microsoft Information Protection Sync Service has `UnifiedPolicy.User.Read`, i was under the assumption that the above mg command would fetch UP.User.Read permission, but it does not.  How to get this roles listed?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read required when an application must be permitted to download unified labeling policies for the tenant. Examples of services that require UnifiedPolicy.Tenant.Read are applications which need work with labels as a service principal identity.

where as UnifiedPolicy.User.Read required when an application must be permitted to read unified labeling policies related to a user. Examples of services that require UnifiedPolicy.User.Read permissions are applications that need to encrypt and decrypt content, based on user’s label policies.

If your doubt is realted to both permission then hope its clear now ,looking into your query the command that you are running does not need these things ,could you please tell us what you are trying to achieve

Thanks

Comment: My objective is to list the available sensitivity labels and apply them to files under impersonation mode.  To implement this i am trying to register an App in AAD with UP.Tenant.Read and UP.User.Read permissions using MG pwsh command.  I am unable to list the UP.User.Read permission as i have explained my initial query.  I have also updated an image for clarity.